# Java Connection Reset

Tags: java, wcf, soap

We are using SOAP 1.1
and we have also created a WCF Webservice which is working fine in SOAP UI
when we tried to get a response via SOAP in java, the connection was established but no data was received.

We got this response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK


Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 12:05:28 GMT
Content-Length: 148
```

After this no SOAP response was received and this error was thrown:

```
ERROR : java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at ICNumber.main(ICNumber.java:113)
```

here is the code snippet:

```
String SOAPRequest ="<soapenv:Envelope"+
"xmlns:soapenv"+
"=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"+
            "<soapenv:Header>"+
            "</soapenv:Header>"+
            "<soapenv:Body>"+
            "<tem:ICNumberValidation>"+
            "<tem:ICNumber>"+
            strIC+
            "</tem:ICNumber>"+
            "</tem:ICNumberValidation>"+
            "</soapenv:Body>"+
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    try {
        //Create socket
        String hostname = "192.168.1.xx";
        int port = 90;
        InetAddress  addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname); 
        SocketAddress sockaddr = null;
        try
        {
            sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, (port));
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ErrorCode-6001");
        }
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        try 
        {
            sock.connect(sockaddr, 10000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println( "ErrorCode-6001");
        }

        //Send header
        String path = "/Service1.svc";
        BufferedWriter  wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        // You can use "UTF8" for compatibility with the Microsoft virtual machine.
        wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        wr.write("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n");
        wr.write("Host: " + hostname + "\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Length: " + SOAPRequest.length() + "\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
        wr.write("SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IService1/ICNumberValidation\"\r\n");
        wr.write("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
        wr.write("User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)\r\n");
        wr.write("\r\n");

        //Send data
        wr.write(SOAPRequest);
        wr.flush();

        //response read
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( sock.getInputStream() ) );
        String line = "";
        String line2 = "";

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            line2 = line2 + line+"\n";
            System.out.println(line2);
        }
        System.out.println(line2);
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Specifically, where you accept/create the connection and where you receive the data.

Comment: What Java SOAP library are you using?

Comment: @thegrinner : i have added the code snippet above itself

Comment: @BenBurns : 

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

Comment: Are there any errors in your IIS event logs?

Comment: @BenBurns no there are no errors

Comment: @BenBurns can you please specify how to check the logs as I could find no errors.

Comment: Hi @RusheelJain did you manage to get this sorted out? Im having the same problem now

Comment: Maybe the response does not end in a EOL, why not use a HTTPClient or SOAP library?